# how to enable SIFT_GPU, GICP_BIN, and GICP_CODE

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Forgive my ignorance if this is a silly question. I set these to =1 in CMakesList.txt and ran
rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam and get the following error:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:69 (FILE):
file COPY cannot find
"/home/lab/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux/bin/libsiftgpu.so".

Am I forgetting a simple step...? CUDA is up and running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11067/how-to-enable-sift_gpu,-gicp_bin,-and-gicp_code/) by [spitzbubchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1017/spitzbubchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spitzbubchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1017/spitzbubchen/) on 2011-08-31**:
Just wondering if there is a quick way to enable/install siftgpu and gicp for rgbdslam...? These do not seem to be ros packages. Or do I have to hunt them and their dependencies down on the internet...? If install instructions were added to the rgbdslam ros wiki that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Siftgpu should be built automatically from the sources included in the rgbdslam package. If it doesn't, I am not sure why (it works for me). You can try and call "make" manually in /home/lab/ros_workspace/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0